# Simple example of drop down menu with a sub menu using razor

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I searched the net looking for a way to add "subItem1" and "subItem2" to the "Home" item menu (in the sample code bellow), but what I found uses either java or complex razor examples. Is there a simpler way using razor only?

```
           <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: If you have to create the submenu items from a database and bind them to the parent, you have to write few lines of code. However, if the submenu names are fixed, then there is an easy way out. Please let me know which is the case...

Comment: The submenu items are fixed. The example bellow (In 1 Answer) works but if you have the css it would be nice to see it. I'm new to html5 and razor so, any good example helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want the following?

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("subItem1", "SubItemOne", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("subItem2", "SubItemTwo", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: And then find or create some CSS to make `ul.menu ul` a dropdown menu.

Comment: That's a good point, it never occurred to me to verify if the default CSS for an MVC site supports cascading menu out of the box or not. What I provided is the accepted pattern of rendering the HTML portion, but you'll still need to get the appropriate CSS to actually get the cascading part to work. You'd think the'd have this as part of the default CSS?

Comment: Thanks Jason, for the example and the follow up. The topic was already marked as answered and unfortunately, I cannot vote it up cause I don't have enough reputations.

Comment: Thanks Yarx for the example. And I finally figured it out you have to click the mark to accept the answer.